# Oracle APEX tabular form make a column Read Only

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I searched many websites for this issue but none of them could solve my problem, I want to disable or make  read only the date column in my tabular form when page load, and also when a user check a checkbox on left hand side of date column only that date row should change to active.

Below is a picture of my app.

[image: picture]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40676325/18747

Comment: Thanks Tony but even a simple alert is not working in my dynamic action, plz check below two pictures links what i did, but it is not working,

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-SV3nhT3s2IVW1UcUE4X3BLUzQ/view?usp=sharing                                                                      

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-SV3nhT3s2IMS1lQ3BhTC1CMzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is because the name attribute of the checkbox is not "f04" it is "f04_NOSUBMIT" as your first screenshot shows.