# making my tabular form dynamic

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a checkbox on a tabular form.  I need to be able to hide it if the submit date is not filled in and show it when a date is there.  Once the checkbox has been clicked, I need to update another field based on the checkbox being clicked or when I hit the update button.  is this possible on a Oracle Apex tabular form in version 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic actions on tabular form fields, but you need to know some Javascript / jQuery / DOM stuff as it can't be done declaratively as it can with page items.

As an example, I created a simple tabular form on the EMP table:
[image]

Using the browser's Inspect Element tool I can see that the HTML for the Ename field on row 3 looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="f03" size="12" maxlength="2000" value="Ben Dev"
    class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0003" autocomplete="off">
```

The relevant bits to note are the name "f03" and the ID "f03_0003".  For all tabular form fields, the name indicates the column, and is the same for all fields in that column.  The ID is made up of the name plus a string to represent the row - in this case "_0003" to represent row 3.

Similarly, the Hiredate fields are all named "f004" and have IDs like "f04_0003".

Armed with this information we can write a dynamic action.  For example, let's say that whenever Ename is empty then Hiredate should be hidden, otherwise shown.  In pseudo-code:

whenever an element with name "f03" is changed, the element with name "f04" on the same row should be hidden or shown.

So we can create a synamic action with a When condition like this:

- Event = Change
- Selection type = jQuery selector
- jQuery selector = input[name="f03"]

i.e. whenever an input whose name is "f03" is changed, fire this action.

The action performed will have to be "Execute Javascript code", and the code could be:

```
// Get the ID of this item e.g. f03_0004
var this_id = $(this.triggeringElement).attr('id');
// Derive the ID of the corresponding Hiredate item e.g. f04_0004
var that_id = 'f04'+this_id.substr(3);

if ($(this.triggeringElement).val() == "") {
    // Ename is empty so hide Hiredate
    $('#'+that_id).closest('span').hide();
} else {
    // Ename is not empty so show Hiredate
    $('#'+that_id).closest('span').show();
}
```

Because Hiredate is a date picker, I needed to hide/show both the field itself and its date picker icon.  I chose to do this by hiding/showing the span that contains them both.  This code could have been written in many different ways.

You could apply similar techniques to achieve your aims, but as you can see it isn't trivially easy.

Comment: this is not working.  I put the variables in and nothing is happening.  if submit date is null then i want to hide two fields and if its not then i want to show those fields. what am i doing wrong?  please help.

Comment: @DarrellLawrence Hard to say without seeing your APEX page and code.

Comment: Tony.. I'm new to this so how can I show you my apex page and dynamic action code?  I basically copied and pasted the javascript code above and replaced it with my codes which were f01 and f02.

Comment: if you can set your application and page up (or a cut-down version thereof) on apex.oracle.com then we can see the HTML and Javascript by viewing the page source,

Comment: i created a workspace on apex.oracle.com.  the workspace is WESLEYAN.  The username is dlawrence@wesleyan.edu and the password is tester. so when hire dt is null i want to hide all columns after and when its not i want to show all columns after hire date.  if you can add the code in the dynamic sql that would be great.  we are on apex 4.2 so i am a little lost with version 5 because it looks a little different.

Comment: yes...quick question.  does submit date have to be editable on the form in order to use it in the dynamic action to control what fields i hide or show?  can it be a display only field?  that date will get populated by another application.  can i still use the field submit date in the dynamic action if its display only.  if not, how would you handle that scenario?

Comment: I set up hire date to be display only.  how can we keep the same functionality on the page when the trigger element which is Hire date is display only?  when the hire date is null hide fields else show fields...

Comment: Done.  Had to change the selector to `span[id^="f04"]` and the Javascript code to `..if ($(this.triggeringElement).text() == "")...`

Comment: I can not get this to work on my application. the code is not firing.  does the span[id^="f04"] work in apex 4.2?

Comment: i made the fields before hire date display only.   This caused the fields that i wanted to hide when the hire date is null to re-appear.  so i think it has something to do with that.  if you take a look now you will see exactly what is happening.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, now your date field is no longer the 4th tabular form item so it is no longer named "f04", it is "f01".  Similar applies to other items.  You need to amend the code accordingly.  From here on I think you should try to address this yourself, so that you gain some understanding.  Use the browser "Inspect Element" function to see the names and IDs of objects on the page.

Comment: In apex 4.2 the code does not hide the simple checkbox column but when I change it to select list(LOV) it does what I expect. The code works fine in version 5.   Thanks for all your help.